# How to improve AODV routing protocol by using ant colony algorithm in ns2

Tags: c++, linux, ns2

My project is to improve the AODV routing protocol by using ant colony algorithm.Now I have found some open source code, but I don’t know how to use it in the protocol.If someone has improved the network protocol, ask you how to operate, what are the steps?thank you

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please, show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you have tried to implement the protocol and you'll get help

Comment: @Bull : Please edit your question to include a link to the `ant colony  software` that you found.